# Save in one managed context only of there are no changes in the other managed object context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsthread

I have two managed object contexts , say MMC and BMC pointing to same persistent store. Created by main thread(MT) and background thread(BT) respectively

There are two fields delta and revision number in all my entities which is being changed by both contexts.

Now, BT takes values from say an Object obj1 from persistent store and posts them to server. When server replies back it provides a new delta and a new revision number for obj1.

Also, while BT is taking to server, values in MMC are being modified, but not saved to persistent store.

I want to save the delta and revision number returned from the server to persistent store, but only if - while background thread was busy taking to the server the revision number did not get changed in MMC.

If it was I want to do keep the delta and revision number of MMC.

How could I possibly achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just save changes, make sure that each thread is observing `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` for the other thread's context, and make sure you use the right merge policy. When the background thread saves changes, the main thread gets the notification and calls `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`. Then:

- If there are no changes on "MMC": Done. Nothing else happens, but if MMC loads an updated object, it gets the value received from the server.
- If there **are** changes on "MMC": If the merge policy for "MMC" is `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`, the unsaved changes in MMC are maintained. The persistent store has the value from the server, but as soon as you save changes on MMC, MMC's value overwrites those values.

As a result, although you'll save changes form the server every time, you won't lose any new changes in MMC. As soon as you save from there, you get whatever new values were entered.